# Encoding changing between two projects

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, character-encoding

I have a visual studio C++ project which gets a return value from a function from another project(used in the form of DLL). While debugging my application, when I Debug the function from the callee, it returns a string where the unicode character \u2019(right quote) is properly encoded and visible in the string. But when I Debug my main project which calls this function, the value of the string variable that reads this value contains EM(end of medium) character where the unicode character is supposed to be.

The code is of the form:

`std::string xyz = ProjectABC::abc(arg1, arg2, arg3);`

The string xyz ends up having the EM character but while debugging projectABC::abc, it returns the value where the character is encoded properly

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `\u2019` interpreted byte by byte `0x20` _Space_ and `0x19` _End Of Medium_…

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I don't see a space before EM. Also, if this is the case, how do you go about solving the issue. From what I have researched, maybe I have to convert the string to string so that there is more space for each character? I have tried MultiByteToWideChar but it didn't solve my issue. I also tried the codecvt library with no luck.

Comment: I have one more theory but don't know how I could test it out. When I'm storing the returned string in std::string, I can't use it to convert to UTF-8 encoding right? Because the EM character will remain EM in the new string as well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `UTF-8` imho. `UTF-8` equivalent for `’` _Right Single Quotation Mark_ is `\xe2\x80\x99`. `\u2019` is its  code in `utf-16BE`. Maybe a space could appear _after_ EM due to different endianness (which is `ucs-2` in Windows, corresponding to `utf-16LE`).